# How do I fix error code CS1503 cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3.'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The error says cannot convert from `float` to `UnityEngine.Vector3`.

This is my code. It is for rigid body movement:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 playerMovementInput;
    private Vector2 playerMouseInput;
    private float xRot;
    
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask floorMask;
    [SerializeField] private Transform feetTransform;
    [SerializeField] private Transform playerCamera;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody playerBody;
    
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    [SerializeField] private float sensitivity;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
    
    private void Update()
    {
        playerMovementInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        playerMouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        
        MovePlayer();
        MovePlayerCamera();
    }
    
    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        Vector3 moveVector = transform.TransformDirection(playerMovementInput) * speed;
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector3(moveVector.x, playerBody.velocity.y, moveVector.z);
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (Physics.CheckCapsule(feetTransform.position, 8.1f, floorMask))
            {
                playerBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void MovePlayerCamera()
    {
        xRot -= playerMouseInput.y * sensitivity;
        transform.Rotate(0f, playerMouseInput.x * sensitivity, 0f);
        playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, 0f, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) but provide it as (properly formatted) text

Comment: sorry this is my first time

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Please update your tags `unityscript` is deprecated, `unity-game-engine` would be appropriate. `rigid-bodies` is completely unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: Also, please post the full error that your receive from Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the second argument of Physics.CheckCapsule() should be of type Vector3, not float. To fix the error, you need to pass a Vector3 representing the top position of the capsule instead of a single float value.

Here's an example of how you can modify the code to resolve the error:

```cs
float capsuleHeight = 8.1f;
Vector3 capsuleTopPosition = feetTransform.position + Vector3.up * capsuleHeight * 0.5f;

if (Physics.CheckCapsule(capsuleTopPosition, feetTransform.position, floorMask))
{
    playerBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: You can multiply `float` and `Vector3` and it does not matter where you place it, this is not an answer to the question.